# CraftyJS how to make a ball move down and bounce

Tags: craftyjs

Is there any way to simulate velocity in an entity in Craftyjs.I am currently making a simple pong game and the ball needs to be "pushed" down,I can't just get it to increase its y value every frame beacause I don't know how to do loops.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even if not post some of your code to make it easier for people to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need bind a 'EnterFrame' event.
sample:

```
ball.bind('EnterFrame', function(){
    this.x += velocityX;
    this.y += velocityY;
});
```